# data not being rendered in internet explorer 11 eventhough I'm forcing http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible to IE=Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have written a script which retrieves data from SharePoint lists. and populates the data onto a page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    init();
});

function init(){
    func();
}

function func(){
    if(GetQueryStringParams("papcat") != undefined){
        //store category in variable
        var PAPCat = GetQueryStringParams("papcat");        
        //query for data that has the catagory associated       
        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'9BBF789F-E5BA-449D-A595-BAA326E2C8FF')/Items?$filter=Category eq '"+PAPCat+"'&$orderby=Reference desc",
            type: "get",
            async: false,
            headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
            success: function(dataObj){
                $.ajax({
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Policies and Procedures Categories')/Items?$select=Title,Id",
                    type: "get",
                    headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                    async: false,
                    success: function(dataObj){
                        //checking if the category exists
                        if(PAPCat > dataObj.d.results.length){
                            $("#output").html("Sorry, that category doesn't exist.");
                        }                           
                        //outputting the category
                        $("#output").append("<h1>"+dataObj.d.results[PAPCat - 1].Title+"</h1>")
                    },
                    error: function(dataObj){
                        $("#output").after("Sorry, an error occured retrieving the records for this category.");
                        console.log(dataObj);
                    }
                });                 
                //checking to see if any records
                //exist against the selected category
                if(dataObj.d.results.length == "0"){
                    $("#output").after("Sorry, no records found for this category.");
                    return; 
                }
                $("#output").after("<table id='policy_and_responsibility' class='output_table'>"+"<tbody>"+"<tr>"+"<td>"+"<h3>Policy and Responsibility</h3>"+"</td>"+"</tr>"+"<tr id='polandresp_col_titles'>"+"<td><b>Ref</b></td>"+"<td><b>Title</b></td>"+"</tr>"+"</tbody>"+"</table>");

                $("#policy_and_responsibility").after("<table id='working_practise' class='output_table'>"+"<tbody>"+"<tr>"+"<td>"+"<h3>Working Practices</h3>"+"</td>"+"</tr>"+"<tr id='workingpractise_col_titles'>"+"<td><b>Ref</b></td>"+"<td><b>Title</b></td>"+"</tr>"+"</tbody>"+"</table>");
                for(var i = 0; i < dataObj.d.results.length; i++){
                    switch(dataObj.d.results[i].Policy_x0020_Type){
                        case "Policy and Responsibility":
                            $("#polandresp_col_titles").after("<tr>"+<td>"+"<a href='/hr/Lists/Policies%20%20Procedures%20Catalogue/DispForm.aspx?ID="+ dataObj.d.results[i].Id +"'>"+ dataObj.d.results[i].Reference.toUpperCase() +"</a>" +"</td>"+"<td class='title'>"+dataObj.d.results[i].Title+"</td>"+"</tr>");
                        break;
                        case "Working Practices":
                            $("#workingpractise_col_titles").after("<tr>"+"<td>"+"<a href='/hr/Lists/Policies%20%20Procedures%20Catalogue/DispForm.aspx?ID="+ dataObj.d.results[i].Id +"'>"+dataObj.d.results[i].Reference.toUpperCase() +"</a>"+"</td>"+"<td class='title'>"+dataObj.d.results[i].Title +"</td>"+"</tr>");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function(dataObj){
                $("#output").after("Sorry, an error occured retrieving the records for this category.");
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        //retrieving all categories
        //from categories list
        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Policies and Procedures Categories')/Items?$select=Title,Id",
            type: "get",
            headers: {"accept":"application/json;odata=verbose" },
            success: function(dataObj){
                console.log(dataObj);
                for(var i = 0; i < dataObj.d.results.length; i++){
                    $("#output").append("<a href='"+_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/SitePages/DVCTest.aspx?papcat="+dataObj.d.results[i].Id+"'>"+ dataObj.d.results[i].Title + "</a><br/>");
                }
            },
            error: function(dataObj){
                $("#output").after("Sorry, an error occured retrieving the categories.");
            }           
        });
    }
}

function GetQueryStringParams(param)
{
    var pageUrl = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var urlVariables = pageUrl.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < urlVariables.length; i++)
    {
        var parameterName = urlVariables[i].split('=');
        if (parameterName[0] == param)
        {
            return parameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine in Chrome, it outputs all the data without a problem. However, in Internet Explorer 11 it doesn't render anything. I believe that it is because Internet Explorer is forcing it's Document Mode to be IE=9. So, outside of any functions, I wrote this little bit of script...

```
if($("meta[http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible]").attr("content") != "IE=Edge")
{
    $("meta[http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible]").attr("content","IE=Edge");
    console.log($("meta[http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible]").attr("content"));

}
```

But it still insists on being set to IE=9.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the masterpage maybe you have the following tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

?